# Codimension of bounded sequences with partial sums constituting again a bounded sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

Let $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ be the vector space of all complex-valued, bounded sequences and let $Z \subset \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ denote the subspace consisting of all bounded sequences such that their partial sums form again a bounded sequence, i.e., $(z_n) \in Z :\Leftrightarrow \left(\sum_{i=1}^n z_i\right) \in \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$.

> What is the algebraic codimension of $Z$ in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$?

I suspect that it is uncountably infinite, but the only thing that I could show is that it is at least countably infinite (by exhibiting an explicit countable family of linearly independent vectors in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}) / Z$.

Motivation: this turned up when I tried to compute the 1st unreduced bounded de Rham cohomology group $H^1_{b, dR}(\mathbb{R})$ of the real line (with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, this is the reason why the sequences in this question are complex-valued). In fact, I have an injective inclusion $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}) / Z \to H^1_{b, dR}(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is uncountably infinite.  To see this note that $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})/\overline{Z}$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space. (you can construct a infinite linearly independent family in here if the example you already constructed isn't in here). Then notice that any infinite dimensional Banach space is uncountable dimension algebraically. Finally since $Z\subset\overline{Z}$ you get the result.

Comment: Thanks! It it easier than I thought.